# Custom field php

Tags: custom-field

Hi I put this php code on my single post php

```
<?php
$custom_fields = get_post_meta($post_id); 
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['_source_link']; //key name
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
    echo $key . " => <a href='" . $value . "'>Click Here</a><br />";
?>
```

however I've got error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it isn't an error, it's a warning:

> ***Warning:*** Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

It's showing as an error because your PHP is configured that way. Research error logging levels for more details.

As for why it's happening:

```
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['_source_link']; //key name
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
    echo $key . " => <a href='" . $value . "'>Click Here</a><br />";
```

What happens if there is no `_source_link` meta field? Or if the field contains an empty array? It is the same as this:

```
$my_custom_field = false
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
    echo $key . " => <a href='" . $value . "'>Click Here</a><br />";
```

Which condenses to:

```
foreach ( false as $key => $value )
    echo $key . " => <a href='" . $value . "'>Click Here</a><br />";
```

This makes no sense, and PHP knows this and outputs a warning.

So instead, don't assume the data is valid, and check beforehand. `empty` is a good way to do this. Here is how I would do it:

```
$my_custom_field = get_post_meta($post_id, '_source_link', true );
if ( !empty( $my_custom_field ) {
    foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
        // display the value
    }
} else {
    // there are no values
}
```